# Checking results of parallelized BLAS routines

Tags: c++, opencl, floating-accuracy, blas

I implemented some parallel BLAS routines in OpenCL. To check if the kernels are correct, I also implemented the same routines in a naive way. After executing the kernels I compare the kernel results with the results of the naive implementation.

I understand that I can not compare `float` values with `==`. I therefore calculate the absolute difference of the two `floats` and check if it exceeds a limit. I already read [this article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) that describes a few other methods of comparing `floats`. My problem however is, that I am unsure about the limit to use to compare the `floats`. In my case the limit seems highly dependent on the BLAS routine and input size.

For example, I implemented `asum` that calculates the absolute sum of a vector of float values. For an input vector of size 16 777 216 the difference between the naive implementation and my parallelized implementation is 96! For an input size of 1 048 576 the difference is only 0.5. Im fairly certain that my kernel is correct, because I checked the results by hand for small input sizes. I'm guessing the difference accumulates due to the large input vector.

My question is, is there a way to calculate the maximal difference that can originate from `float` inaccuracies? Is there a way to know when the difference is definitly due to an error in the kernel code?

Comment: The expected deviation depends on the magnitude of the inputs so there is no single constant limit that you can use

Comment: I know the exact input sizes, because I only want to check some for correctness.

Comment: no strict rules?

Comment: what do you mean by strict rules? I also know that the values of the input vector are in range 1.0 to 10.0.

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique called interval mathematics you can use here.

Instead of having some fixed error which you deem acceptable, you keep track of the *most* and *least* value a given floating point operation could "actually" be referring to.

[Wikipedia has an article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

If I couldn't find a library, what I'd do is create an interval float type.  It contains *two* floats, which represent the highest and lowest (inclusive) values that the interval could represent.

It would override `+` and `*` and `/` and `-` to include the effects of rounding.  It would take work to write.

So if you add `{1.0,1.0}` and `{2.0,2.0}`, the answer would be `{3.0,3.0}`, as the range of values in the `3.0` may be large enough to account for the errors in the `1.0` and `2.0`s.

Subtract 2.0 and the answer becomes `{0.9999999999997, 1.00000000003}` or similar, as the error in the `{3.0, 3.0}` is larger than error implied by `{1.0, 1.0}`.

The same holds for multiplication and division.

It may be shockingly easy for these intervals to reach "every possible number including inf/nan" if you have division involved.  And, as noted, subtraction leads to serious problems; and if you have large terms that cancel, you can easily end up with error bars far larger than you might expect.

In the end, if your OpenCL solution results in a value within the interval, you can say "well, it isn't wrong".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you elaborate why the subtraction of 2.0 results in `{0.9999999999997, 1.00000000003}`? I thought in interval mathematics you subtract the 2.0 from both elements of `{3.0,3.0}`. Why does it result in two different values?

Comment: @Richard the range of values `1.0` represents is `1 +/- floating point error at 1.0`, due to rounding.  When you subtract `2 +/- error at 2.0` and `3 +/- error at 3.0` you get `1 +/- (error at 2.0+error at 3.0)`.  As floating point error goes up with higher magnitudes, this is larger than `error at 1.0`.  So to reflect that, the interval of floating point values is no longer `max value 1.0 could represent, min value 1.0 could represent`, but rather `max value 1.0000000003 could represent, min value 0.999999997 could represent` (those values are not exact).